# RA vs DEC (equatorial coordinate system) 2d plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, astronomy, astropy

I would like to plot some 2d maps showing astronomical sources positions on the sky.

Namely:

I have some data ASCII tables with equatorial coordinates of the sources (RA - right ascension, DEC - declination). 
An example:

[image]

Here RA measured in hours (h), minutes (m), and seconds (s); DEC - in degrees (°), minutes ('), and seconds (").

Right now I'm plotting maps with TOPCAT and it looks like this:

[image]

And everything is fine except that the work with the TOPCAT cannot be scripted. But it is crucial since I have an awful amount of data.

I decided to use **matplotlib** (with astropy), but found out that it is a difficult question **to set the axes in HH:MM:SS and °:':"** as in the plot above.

And astropy tutorial says:

> The axis object, ax, knows to expect angular coordinate values. An
>   important fact is that it expects the values to be in radians, and it
>   expects the azimuthal angle values to be between (-180º,180º). This is
>   (currently) not customizable, so we have to coerce our RA data to
>   conform to these rules!

But "currently" in the tutorial is 2013, maybe it's fixed already?

**So the question is: can I plot my RA/DEC data and set the axes as HH:MM:SS and °:':" with matplotlib?**
*P.S.: Without adding FITS files.*

Comment: Have you looked at and tried with [wcsaxes](https://wcsaxes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? I haven't tried it myself without a FITS file, but you should be able to create your own `WCS` and use that as the `projection` value to `fig.add_axes` (see the getting started part of WCSAxes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you want as the axes ticks labels using `xticks()` and `yticks()` functions. For example, function call `xticks([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"])` will give you ticks labeled as a, b and c at positions of 1, 2 and 3 along the x-axis. So a (somewhat dirty) solution for your problem looks something like this:

1. Plot your coordinates in degrees
2. Configure axes using xticks() and yticks() functions to show hh:mm:ss and °:':" values:

   ```
   # Set up RA coordinates along x-axis
   ticksLocationsRA = linspace(minRA, maxRA, numberOfTicks)
   ticksLabelsRA = degrees_to_hhmmss(ticksLocatoinsRA)
   xticks(ticksLocationsRA, ticksLabelsRA)

   # The same with DEC coodinates
   ticksLocationsDEC = linspace(minDEC, maxDEC, numberOfTicks)
   ticksLabelsDEC = degrees_to_ddmmss(ticksLocatoinsDEC)
   yticks(ticksLocationsDEC, ticksLabelsDEC)
   ```

You only need to write a functions degrees_to_hhmmss() and degrees_to_ddmmss() to convert decimal degrees to strings like HH:MM:SS and °:':" (note, that you can use LaTex notation inside of matplotlib)